# Jasper reports row level security at row level

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, role, row-level-security

I am using jasperserver 5.5. Row security at user level is working fine but role level seems to have some problem.

I inserted this into JIProfileAttribute

INSERT INTO `JIProfileAttribute` (`id`, `attrName`, `attrValue`, `principalobjectclass`, `principalobjectid`)
VALUES
(8, 'test_attr', 'val1,val2,val3, 'com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.domain.impl.hibernate.RepoRole', 7);

This is a snippet of my security file..

```
<principalExpression>
   <![CDATA[authentication.principal.attributes.any {it.attrName in ['test_attr'] }]]>
</principalExpression>
<filterExpression>join_tree.test_attr in ( groovy('authentication.getPrincipal().getAttributes().find{ it.attrName == "test_attr" }.attrValue.split(",").collect{"''" + it + "''"}.join(",").replaceFirst("^''","").replaceFirst("''\$","")'))</filterExpression>
```

All the documentations speak only at the user level. Is there any ways to bring them to role level??

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!